# Why can I not change the PCI configuration registers on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, pci

I want to change Vendor_ID and Device_ID from a PCI device.
However, every change I make will not save and I have no clue why.

First I tried making changes using *setpci* which results in this:

```
# sudo setpci -s 01:00.0 00.w
# 8086
# sudo setpci -s 01:00.0 00.w=168C
# sudo setpci -s 01:00.0 00.w
# 8086
```

Then I tried making the same changes using two different hex editors, editing the *config* file located in */sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/*, but after saving, the file seems unchanged.
I did open it as root and I don't get any errors when saving.

I also tried *ethtool*, but it cannot even access the registers:

```
# sudo ethtool -e wlan0
# Cannot get EEPROM data: Operation not supported
```

I tried everything of the above on both Lubuntu 15.10 and Knoppix 7.6, resulting in the exact same behaviour.

So, why does this happen?
If the registers are protected, is there a way to unprotect them?

Some more information:

- The mentioned pci device is a Intel 7260-AC Wireless Network Adapter
- I want the BIOS to recognize it as a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter, because it's whitelist blocks everything else.
- Modifying the BIOS is not an option.
- I'm running Lubuntu and Knoppix from a USB drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCI Configuration registers typically have attributes such as read only (RO), read write (RW), or other less common ones.

The problem is that you are trying to write a value to a read only register. I have not seen the documentation for this particular device, but I have worked with other Intel PCI devices and I have never seen a RW (read/write) device ID or vendor ID register. For example, look at this [link](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e5-v2-datasheet-vol-2.pdf) on page 96, the VID and DID registers are RO (read only).

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the read only attribute of the register, as this is almost certainly enforced at the hardware level.

Assuming you could change the device ID or vendor ID registers, I imagine this would not necessarily mean a working network adapter, as the BIOS and OS use these values for ACPI and device drivers. There may be a way to fake the device ID and vendor ID in the BIOS, but as you say that is not an option and I don't think it would work anyway.

Depending on how/why your BIOS is whitelisting Qualcomm wireless adapters versus Intel wireless adapters might provide some workaround for this problem. I say the best solution would be to alter the BIOS whitelist somehow, perhaps through an update.

In case it helps, I have [code](https://github.com/scott-walker-llnl/msr-safe/tree/master/csr-safe) that can modify PCI configuration registers of any device (although this will not circumvent hardware level restrictions such as RO, RW, ...). I don't think this will fix your problem but at the very least you can learn more about PCI configuration registers from it.